# "Column invalid..." using COUNT function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions

In SQL Server 2K8 R2, I have a table that tracks user activity with these columns (table is named UserActivity):

```
userFK: nvarchar(35)   // "user1", "user2", "user3", etc
action: nvarchar(35)   // "login", "logout", "vote", "post", "comment", etc
```

I want to run a query that gets the number of times each user logged-in (where action = "login") that returns:

```
userFK      ctActions
-------     ---------
"user1"         50
"user2"         45
"user3"         29
```

The query I thought would work is this:

```
SELECT UserActivity.userFK, COUNT(*) AS ctActions
FROM UserActivity 
WHERE [action] = 'login'
```

But SQL Server is giving me the error:

> Column 'UserActivity.userFK' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add `group by UserActivity.userFK` to your query.  When you are using an aggregate function in sql server, you are required to include your columns in the select list in an aggregate function or in a group by.

Comment: Great thanks! That works. If you guys answer this question I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: @marc_s, I didn't think the version of SQL was relevant which is why I didn't tag it as you corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `UserActivity.userFK` in the group by clause, because you don't use this column in an aggregate function :

```
SELECT UserActivity.userFK, COUNT(*) AS ctActions
FROM UserActivity 
WHERE [action] = 'login'
GROUP BY UserActivity.userFK
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from UserActivity group by userfk